# how to set Different TAG POS= values in imacros

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags, imacros

I'm using iMacros on firefox to automate my work.. but in this website it generates different TAG POS= numbers evrytime

This is my current code:
`TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Pin<SP>it
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=2 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=TXT:Pin<SP>it
WAIT SECONDS=2`

The first line is always `TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Pin<SP>it`

but the third line values always change.. for i.e:

`TAG POS=2 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=TXT:Pin<SP>it
TAG POS=14 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=TXT:Pin<SP>it
TAG POS=13 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=TXT:Pin<SP>it`

I tried replacing the value with '*' mark but then Tag Not Found error displays

Some one please help me!

Thanks,
Blake

Answer (score 0):

there is no "good" solution if you want to use simple imacros iim script, but you can simply use all possible pos indexes so the script will always hit one of them. here is example:

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Pin<SP>it 
WAIT SECONDS=2 
set !timeout_step 1
TAG POS=2 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=TXT:Pin<SP>it 
TAG POS=3 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=TXT:Pin<SP>it 
TAG POS=4 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=TXT:Pin<SP>it 
TAG POS=5 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=TXT:Pin<SP>it 
TAG POS=6 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=TXT:Pin<SP>it 
TAG POS=7 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=TXT:Pin<SP>it 
TAG POS=8 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=TXT:Pin<SP>it 
WAIT SECONDS=2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but it doesn't work. I have already tried it.. There are other buttons around, so when I do this it clicks all matching ones

Comment: This does not answer OP their question.

Answer (score 0):

Hi buddy try this one.

i think you are trying to automate pinterest pins

Its working for me.

`TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Pin<SP>it
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=class:standardForm ATTR=type:submit`

Comment: It doesn't work buddy.. it's just skip this line.. actually I'm repining pins

Comment: Well for me it working perfectly even with repins . are u using imacro for firefox !!! and which version you are on.